# Foreign key problem in Spring Boot - h2 database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, h2

In my spring boot application, I have `User` class something like this :

```
public class User {
@Id @GeneratedValue Long userID;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity = LoginCredential.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "userID",referencedColumnName = "userID")
private LoginCredential loginCredential;
}
```

And another class `LoginCreadential` like this :

```
public class LoginCredential {
@Id @GeneratedValue Long userID;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
User user;
}
```

My application was running fine before I tried to add these relations. Now it doesn't run. It gives me error (a lot), but the important portion is here :

**org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.mua.cse616.Model.LoginCredential.user, referenced property unknown: com.mua.cse616.Model.User.user**

What is the error here? How this can be resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `mappedBy` must have a value which is the name of the field that contains mapping between these entities.

In your example this should be `mappedBy = "loginCredential"`, because `@OneToOne` containing `mappedBy` annotates `User`. `User` on the other hand defines mapping between those entities using `@JoinColumn(name = "userID",referencedColumnName = "userID")` over `loginCredential` field, hence the value of `mappedBy`.

Comment: Thanks.I'm accepting in 6 minutes, but how to access these relational tables? Can you please tell me or refer me something ?

Comment: You need to annotate the entities with `@Entity` and if the name of class differs from name of the table, then also `@Table(name = "name_of_the_table")`.