# Query in arraylist by one element in spring boot h2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a `ClassRoom` class, in my Spring Boot application. Here is what it looks like :

```
public class ClassRoom {

@Id @GeneratedValue Long classRoomID;

ArrayList<User>adminList=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And in my `ClassRoomRepository` class, I have :

```
public interface ClassRoomRepository extends JpaRepository<ClassRoom,Long> {

@Query("select ClassRoom from ClassRoom c where c.adminList = ?1")
ArrayList<ClassRoom> findByAdminList(ArrayList<User> adminList);
/*
@Query("select ClassRoom from ClassRoom c where c. = ?1")
ArrayList<ClassRoom> findByAdmin(User admin);
*/
}
```

I can query to select `ClassRoom` where `ArrayList` of `ClassRoom` gets passed parameter.

**But I want to query to select `ClassRoom where` I pass only one `User` as parameter and returns `ArrayList` of `ClassRoom`.(Commented section-nothing done so far)**

If it is possible in this interface, how can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming you habe many-to-many association using join table, this is what you need,

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT cr FROM ClassRoom cr JOIN cr.admins a WHERE a = ?1")
 List<ClassRoom> findAllByAdmin(final Admin admin);
```

Comment: can I have your mail or some contact, actually I need to discuss with you on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973253/spring-boot-field-is-always-null) and [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985516/jpa-default-column-value-of-custom-class).

Answer (score 1):

When mapping collection , Hibernate requires it to declare it [using interface type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections)  such as `List` , `Set` , `Map` etc. But you are using `ArrayList` to declare the admin list , I am guessing the whole list will be stored to a single column with some binary data type in DB . No one would store the data in this funny way when using RDBMS unless you have strong reason to do it.

From what you describe , `ClassRoom` and `User` seem to be many to many. For demonstration convenience , I would map it as `@ManyToMany`:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class ClassRoom {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name ="classroom_user",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "classroom_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<User> admins = new ArrayList();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class User{

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "admins")
        private List<ClassRoom> classRooms  = Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

Then given an user admin ,to get all of his administrative class rooms :

```java
@Query("select distinct cr from ClassRoom cr left join fetch cr.admins admin where admin = ?1 ")
public List<ClassRoom> findByAdmin(User admin);
```

Or :

```java
@Query("select distinct cr from ClassRoom cr where ?1 member of cr.admins")
public List<ClassRoom> findByAdmin(User admin);
```

Comment: In the `User` class, shouldn't it be `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "user")` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57694662/10305444) , instead of `admins`

Comment: Hi Maifee, No it should be the property name in the `ClassRoom` , so it is `admins` in my example .