# spring boot field is always null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my *Spring BOOT* application, I have a `User` class and a `LoginCreadential` class.

In my `User` class, I have:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity = LoginCredential.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "userID",referencedColumnName = "userID")
@JsonIgnore
private LoginCredential loginCredential;
```

And in my `LoginCraedential` class:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "loginCredential", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
User user;
```

And when I am creating `LoginCreadential` through my *React.js* application like this :

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/login/');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ email: this.state.email,passwordHash:this.state.passwordHash }));
```

I get something like this :

`{"userID":65,"passwordHash":"sad","user":null,"email":"aszzzzzzzzzzdasdasd"},`

My `LoginCreadential` class has two constructors:

```
LoginCredential()
{

}
public LoginCredential(String eMail, String passwordHash,User user)
{
    this.eMail=eMail;
    this.passwordHash=passwordHash;
    this.user=user;
}
```

In my `LoginCredentialController` class, I have :

```
@PostMapping("/login")
void newLoginCredential(@RequestBody LoginCredential newLoginCredential)
{
    List<LoginCredential> userList=repository.findByEmailAddress(newLoginCredential.getEMail());
    if(userList==null || userList.size()==0)
        repository.save(newLoginCredential);
}
```

The user is always null, shouldn't it create an empty `User` or something like this ?

If not how can I achieve it?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant Spring boot code for creating a `LoginCredential`?

Comment: I have added the method from `LoginCredentialController` class in the question, can you please see it ?

Comment: I think I understand, the problem is that the `user` field of `newLoginCredential` is `null`?

Comment: Yes, you have got it. Can you help me with it ?

Comment: @g00glen00b I tried : `newLoginCredential.setUser(new User());` which gives me exception.

Comment: @kostja can you please help here.