# jpa default column value of custom class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, default-value, columndefinition

If I have an entity like this `private Boolean test;`  I can set its default value like this: `@Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")`

But my problem is **how can I set a default value for my custom class?**

Assume I have a `User` class, like this:

```
public class User {

  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue
  Long userID;

  String eMail;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity = LoginCredential.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "userID",referencedColumnName = "userID")
@JsonIgnore
private LoginCredential loginCredential;
}
```

And `LoginCredential` like this:

```
public class LoginCredential {
  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue 
  Long userID;
  String eMail;
   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "loginCredential", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   User user;
};
```

How can I set a default value of `User`, so that when I create `LoginCredential` I get a `User` too.

I tried `User user=new User()` and setting in the constructor. Both gave me exception.

Exception :

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.mua.cse616.Model.LoginCredential.user -> com.mua.cse616.Model.User
```

**How can I resolve this ?**

Comment: @g00glen00b can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In User class:

```
public static User defaultUser(){
       return new User();// or any user you want to use 
        // just don't use the id field, else it will start populating the user database, then it won't be the same value right.. ;) 
}
```

Now where you are saving LoginCredential , just put User.defaultUser() there.

It works, I have done this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map between your `LoginCredential`'s `user` field and `User` class using *JPA* entity relationships.

#### Read:

- [*Multiplicity in Entity Relationships*](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm#BNBQH) in Oracle's JavaEE 7 tutorial
- [*Entity Associations*](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations) in Hibernate user guide

Comment: I have already mapped them actually, I didn't post them for simplification. Now I have edited the question, can you please see again ?